# Can You Mesh Network Google Coral TPUs

Tags: tpu, google-coral, edge-tpu

I believe it is possible to leverage the power of two USB Connected connected Google Coral TPUs  in conjunction with one another (or at least side by side, running their own inferences each).

However, is it possible to leverage two or more Google Coral TPUs which are connected to separate Edge Devices but which sit on the same network connected by hard line ethernets & a switch?

Answer (score 1):

Humn, there is no official API for doing this. So I guess I'll give you a more general answer.

- You may want to look into [kubenetes](https://kubernetes.io/)? I have not tried it, but it seems that they have supports for aarch64 which should works perfectly on the dev board.
- Create servers and communicate via http? I actually have an opensource project calls [restor](https://github.com/namburger/restor), unfortunately it hasn't been maintained. But you may also check out [doods](https://github.com/snowzach/doods).

Possibilities are endless :)

Answer (score 0):

You may run multiple models on a TPU or also you may run multiple TPUs on a single device. Look into this:
https://coral.ai/docs/edgetpu/multiple-edgetpu/

If you would run multiple models on a TPU, the TPU will probably keep switching between models to load them. But, you may combine them using the compiler tool to avoid this.
If you would use multiple TPU devices on a single device, you may tell the interpreter instance which device you mean.

All the information are in the above link.